# Are there any open-source query-language agnostic relational storage engines?

Tags: sql, database, relational-algebra

I've been studying proper relational algebra, from Christopher Date's book [Database in Depth: Relational Theory for Practitioners](http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/Database-Depth-CJ-Date/9780596100124).  Throughout the book he uses the language he and Hugh Darwen came up with in order to convey the theory — [Tutorial D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28data_language_specification%29).  In general I think Tutorial D is a very workable query language, much more flexible than SQL and so I (just for fun) was keen to take a stab at writing a (poor performing, undoubtedly) little RDBMS based on Tutorial D, rather than SQL.

Realizing this is a mammoth of a task even just to make something basic, I wonder if there are existing storage systems available that don't represent tables in the SQL sense, but represent relations in the relational sense and don't assume any particular query language is used to access the data, but rather just provide low-level functions like `product`, `join`, `intersect`, `union`, `project` etc (at the C-level, not at a query language level).

Am I making sense? :)  Basically I'd like to take something like this and stick a Tutorial D (or similar) query interface in front of it.

It's really easy to do everything in memory, but representing the data structures on disk in a fashion that is even mildly efficient is pretty tricky and probably over my head without some serious research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General SQL-based RDBMS that use SQL as an *interface* for *structured* input between the user and the database engine use what is called a [Query Optimizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_optimizer) which takes the query expression and generates a set of [Execution Plans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan).

The most optimal execution plan is then executed on the database; that's what generates result sets.

So, if you took an open source RDBMS implementation and wanted to modify it to accept a different query language, *all* you would have to do would be to translate the query language of your choice into an execution plan.

That's not to say that what you're trying to do is easy. Just that it should be possible, without having to write your own RDBMS. You would need to write a lexer and interpreter for your query language and then figure out how to transfer your interpreted query expression to the database engine's optimizer so that it can generate the execution plans, and execute the most efficient of them.

Take a look a [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) as a compact open source relational database engine.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely need some keywords like this. SQLite is certainly a good place to begin picking things apart.  What I'm trying to do has been done by others by converting the proper relational syntax into SQL and executing that, but that defeats the purpose, since SQL is not truly relational and has many limitations as far as relational algebra is concerned.  I will poke around in SQLite's internals, thanks.

Comment: I've been reading the documentation for SQLite's virtual machine and will take a stab at building on this, though it is still disjointed from the idea of true relational algebra (since it talks about tables and rows), hopefully any translation will be more efficient than using SQL directly as an intermediate... no idea how I'd have a relation-valued attribute though... that's just so distant from SQL's capabilities.  I guess I'll learn a lot to then have a better grounding in the theory though.

Answer (score 3):

Dave Voorhis' Rel already does what you seem to want to build.

http://dbappbuilder.sourceforge.net/Rel.php

Unless of course it is your express purpose to try and build for yourself ...

Comment: I'll study the source, thanks. I'm not looking to re-invent the wheel, no (though something that doesn't depend on Java would be nice).  It's quite possible this just converts the query to one or more SQL expressions to get an equivalent result in an inefficient way (which is what others, such as Dataphor do), so I'll have to check what it's doing.

Comment: @d11wtq: Have you used Dataphor? I downloaded it a while ago but couldn't get it to build and found no support.

Comment: All the links I followed on Dataphor's site were dead yesterday.  That's as far as my attempt at using Dataphor went ;)  I got more information from the wikipedia page about it, which says it converts the TD to SQL and thus (in my eyes) is beside the point :)

Comment: Dataphor site seems to be up now, but the SVN repo is password protected and apparently it's windows-only, while I'm on a Mac.  I'd like (if my dreams were to be realized) something that would (at least in theory) be a client-server based, viable drop in replacement to something like MySQL/PgSQL (i.e. not just some GUI app to play with locally).

Comment: I can't give you much facts about _how_ Rel works internally, you'd have to ask Dave.  It uses the Berkeley engine for storage, and it uses javaCC for the language parsing stuff.  I don't know whether "uses the Berkeley engine" implies "uses SQL under the covers".  I know the Berkeley engine offers an SQL interface, but am uncertain about whether there are or aren't some "lower-level" (record-level) interfaces too.

Comment: BTW why do you dislike dependency on Java ?  Is that any worse than dependency on, say, a VisualC redistributable ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that a front end for Tutorial D would not be query-language agnostic ;)

My vote also goes for Rel.

Hugh Darwen maintains [a list of projects related to TTM](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Projects.html) (the spec for a D language of which Tutorial D is an implementation), I'm sure he would love to hear of your efforts if they come to anything.

Comment: :) I was just thinking of the storage engine (interacted with through C function calls) itself being agnostic of any query language.  Maybe my terminology is incorrect.  Rel does look like it's worth studying, however.  I couldn't find the source for the actual handling of the language itself, it all just looked like Java GUI stuff, but it was 3am when I posted this ;)